# Proof Verification for a proof of product of covering is covering of product

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

If $p_1:B \to A$ and $p_2:Y \to X$ are covering spaces, then I want to prove that $(p_1,p_2): B \times Y  \to A \times X$ is a covering space.

To do that, I need to stick with the definition. So for any point $(a,x) \in A \times X $ and since $p_1, p_2$ are covering spaces implies the existence of the neighborhoods $a \in U \subset A$ and $x \in V \subset X$ such that $${p_1}^{-1}(U)=\cup_{i} U_i$$ where $U_i \equiv U$ by $p_1$

and simmilarly
$${p_2}^{-1}(V)=\cup_{i} V_i$$ where $V_i \equiv V$ by $p_2$

Now for the neighborhood $U \times V$ of $(a,x)$, I have $(p_1 \times p_2)^{-1}(U \times V)=\cup_{i,j}(U_i \times V_j)$ where $U_i \times V_j \equiv U \times V$ by $(p_1,p_2)$

Does this looks correct and complete?

Comment: It is correct and complete. Trust yourself!

Comment: @PaulFrost do you want to post that as an answer?